# Akka Scheduler: Run next only when current run is complete

Tags: java, akka

Scheduling a job using Akka Scheduler goes something like this (at least from the documentation):

```
system.scheduler().schedule(
    Duration.Zero(),
    Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    workerActor,
    new MessageToTheActor(),
    system.dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

I don't however understand how I can ensure the next run only happens when current run is complete. I've been looking around with no success :(

Comment: Scheduler means that you want something in periodic manner, now if your second run is dependent on your first run, then why do you even want to create a scheduler. Just create two actors, one manager actor and other a child actor. When the task is success, the child actor sends a success message to parent actor, so then parent actor asks the child actor to then run the task second time. This guarantees that tasks are run in periodic order and also when the previous one was successful. Hope this helps!

Comment: Indeed this was very helpful. If possible, add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Sure let me add it as answer.

Comment: have a look, I have update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduler means that you want something in periodic manner, now if your `second` run is dependent on your `first` run, then why do you even want to create a scheduler.

Just create two actors, `one manager actor` and other a `child actor`.

When the task is `success`, the `child actor` sends a success message to `parent actor`, so then parent actor asks the `child actor` to then run the task second time. This guarantees that tasks are run in periodic order and also when the previous one was successful.

So basically, you have to implement corresponding matching case class in your receive methods of your `actors`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

A scheduler is the wrong tool for your use case.

An alternative is Akka Stream's [`Sink.actorRefWithAck`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Sink/actorRefWithAck.html#sink-actorrefwithack) (the code below is adapted from the example in the linked documentation and borrows the utility classes defined there). You would need to adjust the worker actor to handle a few messages related to the status of the stream and to reply with an acknowledgement message. The acknowledgement message functions as a backpressure signal and indicates that the actor is ready to process the next `MessageToTheActor` message. The worker actor would look something like the following:

```
enum Ack {
  INSTANCE;
}

static class StreamInitialized {}
static class StreamCompleted {}
static class StreamFailure {
  private final Throwable cause;
  public StreamFailure(Throwable cause) { this.cause = cause; }

  public Throwable getCause() { return cause; }
}

public class MyWorker extends AbstractLoggingActor {
  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
      .match(StreamInitialized.class, init -> {
        log().info("Stream initialized");
        sender().tell(Ack.INSTANCE, self());
      })
      .match(MessageToTheActor.class, msg -> {
        log().info("Received message: {}", msg);
        // do something with the message...
        sender().tell(Ack.INSTANCE, self());
      })
      .match(StreamCompleted.class, completed -> {
        log().info("Stream completed");
      })
      .match(StreamFailure.class, failed -> {
        log().error(failed.getCause(),"Stream failed!");
      })
      .build();
  }
}
```

To use `Sink.actorRefWithAck` with the above actor:

```
final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("MySystem");
final Materializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

ActorRef workerActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(MyWorker.class, "worker"));

Source<MessageToTheActor, NotUsed> messages = Source.repeat(new MessageToTheActor());

Sink<String, NotUsed> sink = Sink.<String>actorRefWithAck(
  workerActor,
  new StreamInitialized(),
  Ack.INSTANCE,
  new StreamCompleted(),
  ex -> new StreamFailure(ex)
);

messages.runWith(sink, materializer);
```

Note the use of [`Source.repeat`](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5/akka/stream/javadsl/Source.html#repeat-T-), which in this case continually emits a `MessageToTheActor` message. Using `Sink.actorRefWithAck` ensures that the actor doesn't receive another message until it's done processing the current message.

The following imports are required (obviously, so is the [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/index.html) dependency):

```
import akka.NotUsed;
import akka.actor.*;
import akka.stream.*;
import akka.stream.javadsl.*;
```

Comment: This seems awesome @Jeffrey. I'm assuming `Source.repeat` repeats the call as soon as the worker actor is done. If this is the case, then how do I ensure there's a pause (let's say 5 seconds) between when the worker actor is done and when it starts processing the next request?

Answer (score 0):

```
system.scheduler().schedule(
    Duration.Zero(),
    Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    workerActor,
    new MessageToTheActor(),
    system.dispatcher(), ActorRef.noSender());
```

Above code means every 5 seconds, scheduler will send `message` to the actor `workerActor`.

And as you know, actor default underlying with just one thread (unless you configure with nr-of-instance>1), that means all your message sent to `workActor` will be buffered in `mailbox`, because just one thread can call `receive` function of `actor`.

In another word, you can always ensure the next run only happens when current run is complete as just one thread worked for the actor by default at the same time.